# 32bit AES equals to 8bit AES?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, rijndael

I am looking into an article about 32bit CPU/MCU software implementation of AES and there are some weird changes over there.
Like shift-rows.
It seems that the shift-rows in the 32bit implementation is shift columns instead.

So my guess is that the 32bit implementation returns different output than the 8bit implementation (the original).

Can you correct me ? or at least explain why it is still equal ?

The article : ["Efficient Software Implementation of AES on
32-Bit Platforms"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-36400-5_13.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

> So my guess is that the 32bit implementation returns different output than the 8bit implementation (the original).
>   Can you correct me ? or at least explain why it is still equal ?

Of course, it's equal.  The AES function (for a specific plaintext, key) is well defined; and if you generate any other result, you're not doing AES correctly.

Of course, while processing, the implementation may decide to lay things out in a different order than what you might naively expect; as long as it generates the same final output, all is well (and, in fact, that is what they did)

> It seems that the shift rows in the 32bit implementation is shift columns instead.

No, in their implementation, they decided to lay the 4x4 matrix in memory so that a 32 bit value contains the 4 bytes in a specific row (and not a column).  That is, the matrix is 'transposed' compared to the representation you would normally expect.  This means that a 'shift row' operation involves rotate operations within the individual 32 bit values (or three of them; the top one remains unchanged), and that the 'mix columns' operation involves logical operations over all 4 32 bit row values.

They did that because doing that made things somewhat more efficient for them than the alternative ordering.  As long as they handle the plaintext->matrix, the matrix->ciphertext operations correctly, and the transpose the key schedule bytes appropriately, everything works precisely as expected.  At every point, the bytes in their transposed state are precisely the same model as the corresponding bytes in the (nontransposed) AES state.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still confused.
If they did what you say they did - then how are they shifting rows (or columns) when the rows aren't continuous ? you will need to do it byte by byte and then I can't see the optimization. (I mean I can't see the optimization in the shitRow operation, as well in subBytes where they implemented it byte by byte as well.)

Comment: @KHSX: with their representation, all the bytes in a single row are contiguous, and hence 3 rotates suffice to do the entire operation.  What is not contiguous are the bytes within a single column; what they do is use logical operations on the 32 bit words to perform mix all four columns in parallel.

Comment: @poncho Are 32 bit table lookups are somehow more secure than 8 bit table lookups with respect to cache timing attacks? I've seen openssl using a 256 entry lookup table that consists of unsigned 32 bit integers...

Comment: @VivekanandV: not more secure; more efficient.  OpenSSL combines the subbytes, mix columns and shift rows into their tables, and so a single lookup does all three.

Comment: @poncho: Can you explain in brief how ?

Comment: @VivekanandV: AES does SubBytes-ShiftRows-MixColumns within a single round.  If a byte $B_{yz}$ had a specific value $x$, then that byte would make a linear contribution (linear based on $sbox[x]$) to a specific column in the state after the round.  Hence, OpenSSL summarizes this linear contributation (in all possible combinations $x$ and $y, z$), and, based on $y, z$, looks up $x$ in a table (Te0 - Te3; because of symmetry, only 4 unique tables are needed), and xor's in the contribution into the resulting state.

Comment: @poncho Thankyou! In their source code I found a function called ```prefetch256t()```. Is that used as a counter measure against cache timing attacks?

Comment: @VivekanandV: that looks like an attempt; however it's not perfect (because you can still task switch between the prefetch256t() and the actual read (with the cache possibly being flushed then), hence leaking some data).

Comment: @poncho Does running that function indefinitely as a separate thread offer some  protection?

Comment: @VivekanandV: again, that would be limited, as different CPU cores (which run the different threads) share the same L2 cache.  What it would provide some protection is that the other thread wouldn't be exactly certain where the AES thread is during the processing stage; however I wouldn't want to depend on that...

Comment: @poncho So in practice, will there be always loop holes in AES implementations that use LUTs? I was trying to create an AES  implementation that works on all platforms irrespective of hardware preferences, therefore I am not using AES NI or instruction sets like that... But I wanted to have a user friendly speed as well as confidence that my implementation will be free from side channel attacks. I even implemented code for calculating SBoxes as well as GF multiplications, but they are eating away my applications performance...  I'm sticking to AES because of its popularity   & wide acceptance!

Comment: @VivekanandV: yeah, I wrote up an AES implementation that tried to avoid any LUTs (instead, using logical, arithmetic operations and shifts for everything); what I ended up with ran about 10x slower than OpenSSL.  I didn't think anyone would be interested, so I never published...

Comment: @poncho Yes, its slow! Is there any point in doing the whole AES calculations in assembly, for any performance gain? Currently, I'm implementing everything in C/C++. I'm newbie to assembly, as I'm only 19 years old. I'm doing all this because I'm very much passionate about Crypto and Computer Security. Should I move further in optimization or go back to LUTs?

Comment: @VivekanandV: well, assembly would rather foil your 'a run-everywhere implementation'.  In addition, you don't know nearly as much about the CPU microarchitecture as the compiler writers do, and so (until you learn a lot more) your assembly code will likely run slower, unless you take advantage of instructions the compiler doesn't have access to, such as AVX or NI.  Still, both have already been done; if you want to learn, that's a viable option; if you just want a fast AES implementation, you can google for a better implementation that what you can write at this point in your learning

Comment: @poncho Thankyou very much ! :)

Comment: @poncho I forgot to mention to you some very important aspects of my implementation !  First, I am using 256 byte Sbox table. Second I'm  interested in AES CTR mode, therefore the only Galois Field multiplications that I'm interested are multiplication by $0x02$ and $0x03$ as far as ```MixColumns()``` is concerned. I am implementing the the above mentioned multiplications like this ```#define GFm2(x) ((x >= 128) ? ((x << 1) ^ 0x11b) : (x << 1))
#define GFm3(x) (GFm2(x) ^ x)``` , but it's still slow than LUT. Third : Does dynamically allocating the Sbox table data, prevent cache timing attacks?

Comment: @VivekanandV: as for why your GFm2 is slow, well, it's because of the conditional branch - modern CPUs hate unpredictable conditional branches (unpredictable == their branch prediction logic guesses wrong a lot of the time).  You might try something like `#define GFm2(x) ((x << 1) ^ ((x >> 7) * 0x11b))`.  As for whether dynamic allocated sboxes prevent cache timing attacks, well, no, they don't.

Comment: @poncho Thankyou for your reply! It's very intriguing & enlightening, to realise that! :) (The branch logic prediction of CPUs is **new** knowledge to me!) For the s-box I read in this site that : https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/1976303 if we use a 256 byte look up table the probability of mounting an attack becomes less... If I am doing AES 256 then substituting the values for it gives me even lower probability, Please can you tell me your thoughts on that ?

Comment: @poncho Thankyou for sharing your idea of removing branching from my ```GFm2(x)``` function. It improved my performance up to 3x . I learned that a two dimensional array is usually not cached well by the cpu and it *most probably* will be accessed from RAM. Will using a 2D array for the Sbox, help reduce vulnerability to a cache timing attack?

Comment: @VivekanandV: the dimensionality of the array doesn't have much to do with it; a large array that is accessed randomly is generally cached well, and will often result in memory accesses.  On the other hand, we generally don't want to do that - the performance of cache misses is hideous, and we generally try to avoid them (in any case, you won't *always* miss the cache, and hence there'll be some memory dependence)

Comment: @poncho Currently I'm using the same old 256 byte s-box as the *only* lookup table. I am satisfied with the performance I got from ```GFm2``` (My program is using AES CTR to encrypt files on my system). Is there a performance friendly method to mitigate a cache timing attack? Currently as a defense, I am calling the OpenSSL authors' ```prefetch256()``` function to grab the whole table quickly. But calling it in *every* round is performance draining. I am unable to circumvent this. Every help and suggestion will be greatly appreciated! :)